# doInBackground takes long to start

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Does anyone know why doInBackground would take long to start? Here is an example:

```
runDoInBackground(){
   print("starting task");
   new MyAsyncTask(someObject,otherObject).execute((Void)null);
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends<Void,Void,Integer>{
   SomeObject someObject;
   OtherObject otherObject;

   public MyAsyncTask(SomeObject someObject, OtherObject otherObject){
      this.someObject=someObject;
      this.otherObject = otherObject;
   }

   @Override
   protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
      print("start background run")
      ... work ... get from server ...
   }

}
```

If the reason for the slow running is other interfering threads (which I doubt), how do I give this one highest priority?

Comment: How do you know it's slow?

Comment: where you see the "print" statements? I am actually logging with system.out.println just to see how long it takes. The after the first print statement, it takes a long time to see the second print statement.

Comment: Whats the time difference?

Comment: All asynctasks use the same executor (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) per default and if there is a task it takes time

Comment: `private class MyAsyncTask extends<Void,Void,Integer>{`... shouldn't this be `private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer>{` ?

Comment: yes that's what I mean @petey

Comment: this code does not compile

Comment: define "long time. how many days ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does depend on the Android version you have how the AsyncTasks are executed. They are executed paralell on API5 (2.0) - API 10 (2.3.3). Beginning from API 11 they are executed serially again per default. As zapl mentioned you have to call

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void)null);
```

to make them run paralell again.

Comment: I have changed to that after the comment. So one question (maybe obvious). If I have more than one AsyncTask and each specify `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, I should assume they are all using the same thread pool, right?

Comment: Yup - but the pool does contain several Threads and even creates new ones on demand up to some number.